# Aggregating different rows into single row

Tags: sql, sybase

Hi I have table like below

```
Column1 Column2  Column3  Column4  

100      Y       N        N
100      N       Y        N
100      N       N        Y
```

**I wanted to see the out like below**

```
100     Y    Y    Y
```

how can we do this in a single query on sybase.
thank for your help

Comment: which Sybase product (ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ? Advantage?) and version? describe the logic you're attempting to apply to get the desired row; what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max()`:

```
select column1, max(column2) as column2, max(column3) as column3, max(column4) as column4
from t
group by column1;
```

This works because `'Y'` is alphabetically bigger than `'N'`.

Comment: just out of curiosity I wanted to know if you apply max(column) when columns has characters does it works ?

Comment: @ChetanVasudevan . . . It takes the maximum values based on the alphabetical ordering.